# Printing polynomials

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, array, homework, formatting

I am taking a class on ruby and our assignment is to take user input and print out a polynomial. Wondering if I can get any feedback to how to improve my code.

```
class PolynomialElements
  attr_accessor :element, :size

  def printElement
    if size.to_i == 0
      num = "#{@element}"
    elsif size.to_i == 1
      if element.to_i.abs == 1
        num = "x"
      else
        num = "#{@element}x"
      end
    else
      if element.to_i.abs > 1
        num = "#{@element}x^#{@size}"
      elsif element.to_i.abs == 1
        num = "x^#{@size}"
      end
    end
  end
end


askAgain = true
polyArray = Array.new

while askAgain
  puts "How many numbers do you want to enter? "
  numString = gets
  num = numString.to_i
  while num > 0
    puts "Enter a value for the Polynomial "
    value = gets
    polyArray.push(value.chomp)
    num -= 1
  end
  outputArray = Array.new
  sizeOfArray = polyArray.length
  polyArray.each do |x|
    var = PolynomialElements.new
    sizeOfArray -= 1
    var.size = sizeOfArray
    if x.to_i != 0
      var.element = x
      if var.element.to_i > 0
        outputArray.push("+")
        outputArray.push(var.printElement)
      elsif var.element.to_i < 0
        outputArray.push(var.printElement)
      end
    end
  end

  if outputArray[0] == "+"
    outputArray.delete_at(0);
  end

  outputArray.each do |x|
    print x
  end
  puts

  puts "Enter y to enter new number or anything else to quit"
  cont = gets
  if cont.chomp != "y"
    askAgain = false
  else
    polyArray.clear
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby agreement is to use `snake_case` to name methods and variables, and not `javaCase`. While you could say it's a matter of taste, it's so common in Ruby world you would do better to just stick with it. Ruby programmers also tend to push for initializing arrays like this:

```
polyArray = []
```

Your PolynomialElements class is not how you use OOP. It has accessor, but what you pass to them aren't parts of its state - those are arguments for `printElement`. More proper abstraction would be to make it hold an array of coeficients, and iterate over it to form a string.

```
class Polynomial
  attr_accessors :coeficients # I think this is a proper name for elements (?)

  def initialize coeficients_array = [0] # default value, just in case
    coeficients = coeficients_array
  end

  def to_s
    coefficients.each_with_object("").with_index do |(coef, str), idx|
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Than, you could use it like:

```
polynomial = Polynomial.new poly_array
puts polynomial.to_s
```

Notice that you don't need to operate on array of characters - Ruby string allows you to work in the same way, just use `append` instead of `push`, and then you just print/puts it instead of printing each character separately.

---

Generally speaking, you barely ever need to keep track of index of iteration manually with Ruby. This:

```
num = numString.to_i
while num > 0
  puts "Enter a value for the Polynomial "
  value = gets
  polyArray.push(value.chomp)
  num -= 1
end
```

could be much better written as

```
num_string.to_i.times do
  # ...
end
```

---

*Ruby way* to do (potentially) infinite loop would be:

```
loop do
  polyArray = []
  # ...
  cont = gets
  break if cont.chomp != "y"
end
```

This seems more readable, as we directly talk to our loop itself by breaking it, instead of using variable as a "middleman".
Also notice how initializing array inside a loop eliminates need for clearing it.

Comment: In `to_s`, rather than create a local variable and mutate it inside the `each` loop, you can just use `reduce` or, better yet, `each_with_object`

Comment: @Jonah I never was a huge fan of each_with_object, but you're probably right.